Use unconventional SQL primitives from SQLAlchemy
I am generating a complex SQL query with SQLAlchemy, and somewhere in the middle of my query, I need an SQL primitive that is not supported by SQLAlchemy. I am assuming the solution to this is adding some raw SQL somewhere in the middle of my code interfacing with SQLAlchemy (I would happily accept another solution though). How can I achieve this?
My specific use case is too complex to explain here, but here is a small illustrative example:

I first perform a FULL OUTER JOIN, which is easily expressible in SQLAlchemy
I then need to use the custom ClickHouse feature WITH FILL STEP that is not supported by SQLAlchemy
Finally, I use a WHERE clause that is easily supported by SQLAlchemy

I want to have Python code that uses SQLAlchemy for steps (1) and (3), but raw SQL for step (2). Note that in my situation, steps (1) and (3) are quite complex, and (2) cannot be expressed in SQLAlchemy, so any frame challenge that exploits a specific insight into this specific example will not help me.
Here is the SQL query I want to run in the end:
-- "full outer join" can be expressed in SQLAlchemy
WITH joined_table AS(
    SELECT 
        table_x.id, 
        table_x.x + table_y.y AS z
    FROM 
        table_x 
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
        table_y 
    ON 
        table_x.id = table_y.id
),

-- "with fill" cannot be expressed in SQLAlchemy
filled_table AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        z
    FROM 
        joined_table
    ORDER BY 
        z
    WITH FILL 
        STEP 10
)

-- "where" can be expressed in SQLAlchemy
SELECT 
    id, 
    z
FROM 
    filled_table
WHERE 
    z < 200

PS: I tried to figure this out through ChatGPT, but its suggestions look very messy, forcing me to manipulate strings myself. I am hoping to avoid that if at all possible.
Unsuccessful Attempt
Here is an unsuccessful attempt using .with_hint (as suggested by Gord Thompson in the comments):
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, table, column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

table_x = table(
    'table_x',
    column('id', Integer),
    column('x', Integer)
)
table_y = table(
    'table_y',
    column('id', Integer),
    column('y', Integer)
)

# Create a SQLAlchemy engine and session
engine = create_engine(f'clickhouse://default:@{clickhouse_host}:{8123}/{database}')
session = Session(engine)

# joined_table
joined_table = table_x.outerjoin(table_y, table_x.c.id == table_y.c.id, full=True)
joined_table = select(
    table_x.c.id,
    (table_x.c.x + table_y.c.y).label('z')
).select_from(joined_table).subquery()
# filled_table
filled_table = select(joined_table).with_hint(joined_table, "WITH FILL STEP 10")
# final
final_query = select(filled_table.c.id, filled_table.c.z).where(filled_table.c.z < 200)

# Print the SQL query
print("\nGenerated SQL Query:")
print(str(final_query.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})))

This generates the following SQL, which does NOT include the relevant WITH FILL part:
SELECT anon_1.id, anon_1.z 
FROM (SELECT anon_2.id AS id, anon_2.z AS z 
FROM (SELECT table_x.id AS id, table_x.x + table_y.y AS z 
FROM table_x FULL OUTER JOIN table_y ON table_x.id = table_y.id) AS anon_2) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.z < 200


Have you tried using .with_hint(joined_table, "WITH FILL STEP 10") to see if that works?

@GordThompson No I have not tried that - thanks for the suggestion! Sounds interesting but also somewhat hacky... If there is no better option, I will try that.

@GordThompson I tried using with_hint, but failed (I added details on my attempt to my question above).
